# For i utiliza apenas a última variável - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Bom dia!

Estou com um projeto que estou melhorando e gostaria de fazer um **For i** para rodar todas as variáveis dentro do projeto, porem ao rodar ele aplica o projeto apenas para a ultima variável.

**Código:**

```
for i in ['1', '2', '3']:

    arquivo5 = open(r'\Texto para SAS\Vers' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w')

with open(r'\DataMining Python\Respostas.txt') as stream:
    with open(r'\Texto para SAS\teste.txt', 'r') as arq:

        palavras = arq.readlines()


        for line in stream:
                for word in palavras:

                    if word.lower() in line.lower():

                        a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n\r')

                        arquivo5.writelines(a)
                        print(i)


arquivo5.close()
```

**Resposta.txt:**

```
Muita cobranca para meu time
Cobrar nao e viver
Nao me cobre por isso
```

**teste.txt**

```
cobra 
cobranca
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por causa da indentação, o seu for só roda a linha de atribuição a `arquivo5`. No final, você modificou `arquivo5` três vezes antes de entrar no `with`, então quando entra no `with` ele executa só uma vez com o último valor atribuido.

Basta modificar a indentação pra incluir a lógica dentro do `for`:

```
for i in ['1', '2', '3']:
    arquivo5 = open(r'\Texto para SAS\Vers' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w')   

    with open(r'\DataMining Python\Respostas.txt') as stream:
        with open(r'\Texto para SAS\teste.txt', 'r') as arq:        
            palavras = arq.readlines()        
            for line in stream:
                    for word in palavras:

                        if word.lower() in line.lower():

                            a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n\r')

                            arquivo5.writelines(a)
                            print(i)
    arquivo5.close()
```

Algumas melhorias que eu sugeriria pro seu código:

- Troque o ['1', '2', '3'] por um `range`. Assim, você pode aumentar o número de arquivos sem ter que gastar teclado digitando uma lista.
- Ao invés de usar o `open` e `close`, use o `with`, como está fazendo com os outros arquivos. Isso cria um gerenciador de contexto, e garante que seu arquivo vai ser fechado corretamente não importa o que aconteça dentro do bloco.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
for i in range(1, 4):  # Inclui o 1, não inclui o 4
    with open(r'\Texto para SAS\Vers' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w') as arquivo5:
        with open(r'\DataMining Python\Respostas.txt') as stream:
            with open(r'\Texto para SAS\teste.txt', 'r') as arq:  
                palavras = arq.readlines()

                for line in stream:
                    for word in palavras:

                        if word.lower() in line.lower():
                            a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n\r')

                            arquivo5.writelines(a)
                            print(i)
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado! desculpe a duvida noob

Comment: @Gigle imagina, é errando que se aprende!